# Custom grid in foundation email?

Tags: html, email, zurb-foundation

I need a different sized grid within the standard grid layout.

and I get this result

[image: foundation email result]

the result I need is this

[image: foundation email result2]

any ideas??

```
it is much code and I must add many details that can be published
```

[This's the code](https://jsfiddle.net/11v7twm0/)

Comment: where is the html and css that you have tried? post that code here and a link to a https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

you may not find immediate assistance here with Zurb Foundations (specifically for email) because of zurb's stack behind inky markup and the dependencies involved, making it a bit discouraging for people to offer help right away. I was hesitant to answer, too, because I can't use inky on something like codepen. Just wanted to explain why you've not received much feedback. I came up with this for you, however:

```
<table class="row">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="large-6 first columns">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/580x500">
                </a>
            </th>
            <th class="large-6 last columns">
                <table class="row">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="large-12 first last columns">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/580x50">
                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="row">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="large-6 first columns">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/290x210">
                                </a>
                            </th>
                              <th class="large-6 first columns">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/290x210">
                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="row">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="large-6 first columns">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/290x210">
                                </a>
                            </th>
                              <th class="large-6 first columns">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/290x210">
                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Try this codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZLzPv